# polars: select values from group_by list with a value from another column

Tags: python, python-polars

Starting with df:

```
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {   "seq":  "foo bar bar duk duk baz baz baz zed".split(), 
        "seq_grp": "aa bb bb dd dd cc cc cc zz".split(),
        "match":   "aa cc bb dd dd ff cc cc yy".split(),
        "score":        [10, 8, 20, 8, 7, 5, 6, 4, 6],
     
     }
)
```

I got:

```
FRAME_1
┌─────┬─────────┬───────┬───────┐
┌─────┬─────────┬───────┬───────┐
│ seq ┆ seq_grp ┆ match ┆ score │
│ --- ┆ ---     ┆ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ str ┆ str     ┆ str   ┆ i64   │
╞═════╪═════════╪═══════╪═══════╡
│ foo ┆ aa      ┆ aa    ┆ 10    │
│ bar ┆ bb      ┆ cc    ┆ 8     │
│ bar ┆ bb      ┆ bb    ┆ 20    │
│ duk ┆ dd      ┆ dd    ┆ 8     │
│ duk ┆ dd      ┆ dd    ┆ 7     │
│ baz ┆ cc      ┆ ff    ┆ 5     │
│ baz ┆ cc      ┆ cc    ┆ 6     │
│ baz ┆ cc      ┆ cc    ┆ 4     │
│ zed ┆ zz      ┆ yy    ┆ 6     │
└─────┴─────────┴───────┴───────┘
```

Since I intend to select specific values per group, for each `seq`, I did the group_by:

```
grouped_df = df.group_by("seq", maintain_order=True).agg(df.columns[1:]).with_columns(col("seq_grp").list.get(0) )
```

getting:

```
FRAME_2
┌─────┬─────────┬────────────────────┬───────────┐
│ seq ┆ seq_grp ┆ match              ┆ score     │
│ --- ┆ ---     ┆ ---                ┆ ---       │
│ str ┆ str     ┆ list[str]          ┆ list[i64] │
╞═════╪═════════╪════════════════════╪═══════════╡
│ foo ┆ aa      ┆ ["aa"]             ┆ [10]      │
│ bar ┆ bb      ┆ ["cc", "bb"]       ┆ [8, 20]   │
│ duk ┆ dd      ┆ ["dd", "dd"]       ┆ [8, 7]    │
│ baz ┆ cc      ┆ ["ff", "cc", "cc"] ┆ [5, 6, 4] │
│ zed ┆ zz      ┆ ["yy"]             ┆ [6]       │
└─────┴─────────┴────────────────────┴───────────┘
```

I am trying to fish out i.e. cases where `seq_grp` matches element from `match` list and check if it has the max value in the `score` list.

getting:

```
FRAME_3
┌─────┬─────────┬───────┬───────┐
┌─────┬─────────┬───────┬───────┐
│ seq ┆ seq_grp ┆ match ┆ score │
│ --- ┆ ---     ┆ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ str ┆ str     ┆ str   ┆ i64   │
╞═════╪═════════╪═══════╪═══════╡
│ foo ┆ aa      ┆ aa    ┆ 10    │
| bar ┆ bb      ┆ bb    ┆ 20    │
│ duk ┆ dd      ┆ dd    ┆ 8     │
│ baz ┆ cc      ┆ cc    ┆ 6     │
└─────┴─────────┴───────┴───────┘
```

While in this minimal example I could get almost there using:

```
df.filter(col("seq_grp") == col("match")).group_by("seq").agg(pl.all())
   .with_columns(col("score").list.max())
   .with_columns(col(["seq_grp", "match"]).list.get(0) )
```

I would like to be able to get the list index (looking at `FRAME_2`) row:

```
 baz ┆ cc      ┆ ["ff", "cc", "cc"] ┆ [5, 6, 4] │
```

of a top scoring non-cc match and its values:
│ **baz** ┆ **cc**      ┆ [**"ff"**, "cc", "cc"] ┆  [**5**, 6, 4]

Comment: Why is `foo aa` in FRAME_3 but `zed zz` isn't?

Comment: Does that mean you want `bar, bb, cc, 8` as the other result? And `aa, dd` have no non-matches? Can you show the full final output dataframe you expect?

Comment: @jqurious I thought they were trying to figure out how to get to FRAME_3 but I guess they also said they want the list index so, yeah, I don't know.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor Aye, it's a bit confusing alright. I believe the final `df.filter` code example produces FRAME_3 - I suppose the reason for wanting the list index could also be important as "there may be a better way".

Comment: @jqurious what?!?! an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), no way.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor `zed` has no match between `seq_grp` and `match`.

Comment: What should the full final result be? It sounds like you want *"any match per group"* as 1 condition i.e. `df.filter(pl.col("match") != pl.col("seq_grp"), (pl.col("seq_grp") == pl.col("match")).any().over("seq_grp"))` but it's not clear if you also want the other matches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work?

```py
df.lazy().filter(pl.col("match") != pl.col("seq_grp")).group_by(
    ["seq", "seq_grp"], maintain_order=True
).agg(
    best_non_match=pl.col("match").get(pl.col("score").arg_max()),
    top_score=pl.max("score"),
).collect()
```

```
shape: (3, 4)
┌─────┬─────────┬────────────────┬───────────┐
│ seq ┆ seq_grp ┆ best_non_match ┆ top_score │
│ --- ┆ ---     ┆ ---            ┆ ---       │
│ str ┆ str     ┆ str            ┆ i64       │
╞═════╪═════════╪════════════════╪═══════════╡
│ bar ┆ bb      ┆ cc             ┆ 8         │
│ baz ┆ cc      ┆ ff             ┆ 5         │
│ zed ┆ zz      ┆ yy             ┆ 6         │
└─────┴─────────┴────────────────┴───────────┘
```

Comment: yes, this gives me the top scores of `best_non_match` ;). Thank you very much. It is really useful for double checking the supposedly correct matches. Biology has it quirks...

Answer (score 0):

While writing down this question I realized that probably I will able to get most of the ~correct values doing just FILTER_A.
The issue is that the real data I am processing is a quite more complex and I really wanted to poke around lists in columns obtained by `group_by("query")` to check that indeed I am selecting the right thing. Just now realized that this should be much easier (for me at least...) to do it using dictionaries.

The real data looks like this (one row after group_by("query")

```
{'query': 'tRNA-Arg-TCT-1-1.spld__strt34__count10__3805664747475775435',
 'profile_mdl': ['spld_Arg-TCT',
  'tRNA-Arg-TCT',
  'tRNA-Val-AAC',
  'tRNA-Asn-GTT',
  'tRNA-Val-TAC'],
 'mdl_from': [34, 37, 42, 37, 42],
 'mdl_to': [73, 86, 69, 73, 69],
 'seq_from': [1, 4, 9, 3, 9],
 'seq_to': [40, 40, 36, 39, 36],
 'e_value': [3.2e-11, 1.5e-09, 0.00014, 0.00014, 0.00018],
 'query_match_len': [40, 37, 28, 37, 28],
 'query_spliced': [True, True, True, True, True],
 'profile_spliced': [True, False, False, False, False],
 'profile_isotype': ['Arg-TCT', 'Arg-TCT', 'Val-AAC', 'Asn-GTT', 'Val-TAC'],
 'query_isotype': ['Arg-TCT', 'Arg-TCT', 'Arg-TCT', 'Arg-TCT', 'Arg-TCT']}
```

In this case I want:

`profile_mdl: spld_Arg-TCT`  (first element in all the lists)
based on comparison with 'tRNA-Arg-TCT'
in both cases I have `'profile_isotype' == 'query_isotype'`, but the `spld_Arg-TCT` has a lower `e-Value` and larger `query_match_len`

If the situation would be reversed (`spld_Arg-TCT` `query_match_len << tRNA-Arg-TCT query_match_len' the whole query group` 'query': 'tRNA-Arg-TCT-1-1.spld__strt34__count10__3805664747475775435'`, goes to the bin.

Last but not least, I am sorry for being rather fuzzy specifying my question, but as you may imagine filters/selection rules for such data are being developed in an iterative process. One never knows why some counterintuitive match match between sequences pops up.